# How can I make my background to see full?

Tags: html, css

I have this page:

http://test.dac-proiect.ro/landing-page/index.html

As you can see my background (two circles) can not be seen completely.
I put an image to understand better.

http://i61.tinypic.com/2a0gl4w.jpg

This is code HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="bg-verde">
        <div class="container-video">
             <div class="text-sus">
                <p>Set us perspiciatis</p>
                <p>unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore <p>
             </div>
             <div class="video">
                  <img src="images/VIDEO.png" style="width:100%;height:auto;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- <div class="imagine1"><img src="images/CERC-ALBASTRU.png" style="width:70%;height:auto;float:left;"></div>-->
        <div class="ion" style="width:100%;height:50px;background:red;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is code CSS:

```
.content{
   background: url(images/VERDE.png);
   width:70%;
   height:1000px; //this height is fixed, I tried to put 100% or car but still does not alter the situation
   margin:0 auto;
   background-repeat:no-repeat;
   background-size:cover;
}
.imagine1{
   display:none;
}

.container-video{
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   background:url(images/BODY-VERDE.png);
   margin:0 auto;
   overflow:auto;
}

.bg-verde{
    height:inherit;
    background:url(images/bg2.png);
    background-size:cover;
 }
```

Can you please help me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: sorry...you want the image to be appeared as full background?

Comment: yes...my background is composed of two circles but unfortunately do not see everything

Comment: Use background-size:contain; instead of background-size:cover;

Comment: Try `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/b5im0w.png look how they look when they replace with "body" breaks down design ..

Comment: is not well with the background: 100% 100% and you try and see what it sees ugly

Comment: .bg-verde {
   background: url(images/bg2.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px; /* height is like window height minus header height */ /* then it will shows you with in the page of window view itself */ /* even if you want make it with by document height you could do  using jquery */ 
}